# Why is Log4Net not working in every class?

Tags: c#, config, log4net

I am using log4net.Ext.Json.

Here is my App.config:

```
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="logs\server.json" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
                <default />
                <remove value="log4net:UserName" />
                <remove value="log4net:HostName" />
                <remove value="log4net:Identity" />
                <remove value="log4net:Properties" />
                <remove value="log4net:LocationInfo" />
                <remove value="log4net:ThreadId" />
                <remove value="log4net:Timestamp" />
                <member value="time:timestampUtc" />
                <member value="level:level" />
                <member value="logger:logger" />
                <member value="message:message" />
                <member value="exception:exception" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

Here is my program:

```
namespace Chat.Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string endpointAdress = "http://localhost:8085/ChatService2";

            try
            {
                using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ChatService2)))
                {

                    var baseAddress = "http://localhost:8090/";
                    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);

                    log.Info("Main: Starting ServiceHost");
```

This is working I can find the log info in my json file.
But here is a class in the same project:

```
namespace Chat.Server
{
    public class ChatClient : IChatServiceCallback2
    {
        private IChatService2 chatService;
        private InstanceContext context;
        private string id;
        private ClientWebSocket _webSocket;
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public ChatClient(string endpointAddress)
        {
            context = new InstanceContext(this);

            var wsDualBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
            var wsDualEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);


            DuplexChannelFactory<IChatService2> wsDualFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChatService2>(context, wsDualBinding, wsDualEndpoint);

            IChatService2 service = wsDualFactory.CreateChannel();

            this.chatService = service;
            this.id = chatService.RegisterClient();
            log.Info("ChatClient: Creating new ChatClient");
        }
```

And this log info is not written in my log json.

I can't figure out why.
I have tried this: `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "App.config", Watch = true)]`, but still not working.

Maybe someone had the same problem.

Comment: may I ask why `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` instead of `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ChatClient));` what does your code even resolve to on a private static fields initialization?!?

Comment: @RandRandom I don't get your comment. I found this: `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` a lot. And I have tried yours with `typeof(ChatClient)`. But nothing changes.

Comment: Can you confirm that a `ChatClient` is created using the given ctor? Do you have an equivalent logger in other classes and do you get a log from there?

Comment: @JürgenRöhr I figured out why it wasn't logging. Because I run multiple instances of my program. I have fixed it with `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"`.